# how to create line chart using the datas from mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, charts, linechart

I want to create a line chart using the datas from mysql and my resultant  json is looking like this.

```
[{"date1":"2014-05-07","count":"1","name":"Aparna Giridhar"},{"date1":"2014-05-27","count":"1","name":"Aparna Giridhar"},{"date1":"2014-05-27","count":"2","name":"Yatish Bhargava"},{"date1":"2014-05-28","count":"3","name":"Yatish Bhargava"},{"date1":"2014-05-23","count":"2","name":"Natesh Bargi"},{"date1":"2014-05-28","count":"2","name":"Natesh Bargi"},{"date1":"2014-05-28","count":"3","name":"Divya Raghavan"},{"date1":"2014-05-30","count":"3","name":"Shreya P"},{"date1":"2014-05-07","count":"2","name":"Sharan Bains"},{"date1":"2014-05-09","count":"2","name":"Sharan Bains"},{"date1":"2014-05-16","count":"5","name":"Sharan Bains"},{"date1":"2014-05-28","count":"1","name":"Sharan Bains"},{"date1":"2014-05-30","count":"1","name":"Sharan Bains"},{"date1":"2014-05-26","count":"5","name":"Vergis Koshy"},{"date1":"2014-05-02","count":"1","name":""},{"date1":"2014-05-12","count":"2","name":""},{"date1":"2014-05-13","count":"5","name":""},{"date1":"2014-05-14","count":"1","name":""},{"date1":"2014-05-15","count":"1","name":""},{"date1":"2014-05-17","count":"1","name":""},{"date1":"2014-05-30","count":"2","name":"Deepti Karthik"}]
```

In my graph x axis i want dates,y axis as count and lines as names.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with google charts if you encode the data to php

Encode JSON with PHP on server side:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

Parse the JSON string with native Javascript API-object "window.JSON" on client side. Browsersupport [1](http://www.kometschuh.de/GoogleChartToolswithJSON.html)

```
window.JSON.parse(jsonData);
```

tracker.php

```
<?php
    $dbhost="localhost";
    $dblogin="root";
    $dbpwd="";
    $dbname="myDB";

    $db =  mysql_connect($dbhost,$dblogin,$dbpwd);
    mysql_select_db($dbname);    

    $day = date('d');
    $month = date('m');
    $lastMonth = (string)($month-1);    
    $lastMonth = strlen($month - 1) == 1? '0'.$lastMonth : $lastMonth;

    $SQLString = "SELECT    
            count(analytics.day) as counts,
            analytics.day, month,
            date FROM analytics  
            WHERE year = '2012' AND month = '$month' 
            OR (month = '$lastMonth' and day > '$day') 
            GROUP BY day, month 
            ORDER BY date asc";     

    $result = mysql_query($SQLString);    
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);   

# set heading   
    $data[0] = array('day','counts');       
    for ($i=1; $i<($num+1); $i++)
    {
        $data[$i] = array(substr(mysql_result($result, $i-1, "date"), 5, 5),
            (int) mysql_result($result, $i-1, "counts"));
    }   
    echo json_encode($data);
    mysql_close($db);
?>
```

html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Kometschuh.de Tracker</title>
    <!-- Load jQuery -->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <!-- Load Google JSAPI -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
            var jsonData = $.ajax({
                url: "php/tracker.php",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false
            }).responseText;

            var obj = window.JSON.stringify(jsonData);
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(obj);

            var options = {
                title: 'Kometschuh.de Trackerdaten'
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(
                        document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Reference](http://www.kometschuh.de/GoogleChartToolswithJSON.html)

Comment: am getting error @ var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(obj); not an array..

Comment: did you parse the json data ? - see the second sstep

Comment: if you read the link it says to 'Set up an array and the returned data have to represents also this array structure. ... build it on server side'